# How to find strings with * in pandas data frame using re

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a string with `*A*` in the data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col_1":["AAA","BBB","CCC"],
    "col_2":[4,5,6],
    "col_3":[107,800,300],
    "col_4":[1,3,5]
})

#0  1   2   3
#0  AAA 4   107 1
#1  BBB 5   800 3
#2  CCC 6   300 5
```

This line gives the error:

```
df['col_1'].str.match("*A*")
```

It is not working  and I am getting an error:

> ```
> line 615, in _parse
> source.tell() - here + len(this))
> sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
> ```

I have also following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "col_1":["AAA","BBB","CCC"],
  "col_2":[4,5,6],
  "col_3":[107,800,300],
  "col_4":[1,3,5]
 })

 def findItems(df, findText, colName):
    mask = df[colName].astype('str').str.match(findText) 
    print("\n mask",mask)

 The above code is also not working
```

Comment: Use `df['col_1'].str.contains('A')`?

Comment: What are you looking to do here? Find strings that contain an A or strings that contain * A *?

Comment: What @Zero said... but, you've got your regex wrong.  `'*'` in regular expressions means repeat this 0 or more times.  I think you meant `'.*'` where the `'.'` means any character and the `'*'` is repeat that any character 0 or more times.  So `df['col_1'].str.match(".*A.*")`

Comment: @piRSquared nicely explained. but if that is the desired operation `df['col_1'].str.match("A")` would be enough or the classical find `df['col_1'].str.find("A") >= 0` (apart from Zero's already mentioned contains)

Comment: @AntonvBR Yeah, I agree.  I was attempting to impart some insight into why `*A*` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples for you that should answer your question.

I think you might be looking for: `str.match(".+A.+")` which would mean any char(s) followed by `A` followed by any char(s), i.e if `str.contains('A')` doesn't help you.

Credit to all the commenters too.

```
import pandas as pd

# Let us create a serie as df['col'] is actually a serie.
s = pd.Series(['A','AA','AAA','aaa'])

print(s.str.contains('A').values)             # [ True  True  True False]
print(s.str.lower().str.contains('a').values) # [ True  True  True  True]
print(s.str.match(".*A.*").values)            # [ True  True  True False]
print(s.str.match(".+A.+").values)            # [False False  True False]
print(s.str.match(".+[Aa].+").values)         # [False False  True  True]
```

Comment: if I have pattern as function argument the how do I pass it

Comment: how do I us re module in this case